# How ca I reshape y_train , y_validation from train_generator?

Tags: classification, cnn, training

I retrained ResNet-50 for iris flower classification in tensorflow using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2, random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from random import shuffle 
from IPython.display import SVG
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd 
import shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
from IPython.display import Image, display
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
print(os.listdir("./iris recognition/flowers"))

labels = os.listdir("./iris recognition/flowers")
num_classes = len(set(labels))
IMAGE_SIZE= 224


# Create model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Do not train first layer (ResNet) as it is already pre-trained
model.layers[0].trainable = False

# Compile model
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
train_folder = './iris recognition/flowers'

image_size = 224
data_generator =  tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    validation_split=0.2)# set validation split

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_folder,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training'
    )
validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_folder,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation'
    )

NUM_EPOCHS = 70
EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE = 5
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = './working/best.hdf5',
                                  monitor = 'val_loss',
                                  save_best_only = True,
                                  mode = 'auto')
import math

fit_history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=10,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
#     validation_steps=10,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper])
model.load_weights("./working/best.hdf5")
```

After that I saved all the training data and validation data extracted from train generator as follow:

```
    from platform import python_version_tuple
    
    if python_version_tuple()[0] == '3':
        xrange = range
        izip = zip
        imap = map
    else:
        from itertools import izip, imap
    
    import numpy as np
    
    x, y = izip(*(train_generator [i] for i in xrange(len(train_generator))))
    x_train, y_train = np.vstack(x), np.vstack(y)
    
    x1, y1 = izip(*(validation_generator [i] for i in xrange(len(validation_generator))))
    x_val, y_val = np.vstack(x1), np.vstack(y1)
    
    import pickle as pkl
    #to save it
    with open("validation.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pkl.dump([x_val, y_val], f)
    #to load it
    with open("validation.pkl", "rb") as f:
    x_val, y_val = pkl.load(f)
```

The shape of the obtained **y_val ** is (83, 3) I wanted to reshape it to get a shape of (83,) by trying this:

```
y_test = y_val.reshape(y_val.shape[0],)
```

However I got this error : **valueError: cannot reshape array of size 249 into shape (83,)**

Any suggestions please?!

Comment: The error tells you what the issue is, since the array contains 249 items (83 times 3) you can't simply reshape it to a shape of `(83, )` since you have more items than there is space. Think about why you want to reshape your array and only select the 83 items from the original array that you want.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I wanted to reshape it that way because as I know as the shape of x_val is (83,224,224,3) so the shape of y_val which contains the labels should be (83,)